# Javascript Number and Currency localization

Tags: javascript, localization

I've run into numbers and currency localization in JavaScript

What I need is a convenient **library** for that.

I am responsible for setting the decimal separators, currency, etc.

Please post the best links you think

Comment: If you pass the separators and currency from django... what other library do you need? o.o

Comment: it is strange, but the best thing I've found ever is built in here http://www.ejschart.com/examples/formatters/number.html

Comment: @Khez: I need a client-side library written in JavaScript

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[Most modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=intl) have built in support [internationalisation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) in the form of the global Intl object and extensions to Number, String & Date.

```
var money = 123456.12;

// display with correct formatting
money.toLocaleString('de-DE'); // "123.456,12"

// for currency, bad as we're leaving the precision to the gods of floating point numbers
money.toLocaleString('en-GB', { style: 'currency', currency: 'GBP' }); // "£123,456.12"

// for currency, good as we're using strings...
new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format('12312.12')
```

If you're not familiar with why floating point numbers are bad for currency info check this out on [floating point numbers](https://www.avioconsulting.com/blog/overcoming-javascript-numeric-precision-issues)

Comment: This looks like the best approach. Does anyone know of good polyfills for this?

Comment: Ok after some research, it appears that the best resource as of may 2019 is the Intl package: https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/

Answer (score 4):

The best answer for you probably depends on what javascript libary, if any, you are currently using. But YUI has support for [number/currency formatting with internationalization](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/datatype/#formattingnumbers), and it is a solid and well-designed library.

Example:

```
alert(Y.DataType.Number.format(123123123.176,{
    prefix: "€",
    thousandsSeparator: ".",
    decimalSeparator: ",",
    decimalPlaces: 2,
    suffix: " (EUR)"
}));
```

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft has created a useful plugin for jquery:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/10/jquery-globalization-plugin-from-microsoft.aspx

Comment: The repository is dead, but I believe this is its replacement: https://github.com/jquery/globalize

Answer (score 1):

This post is quite old, but I post a response in case it's interesting someone.

I found the [numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/) library pretty useful to do this.
You can define your custom formats and add localized files in the same way that 'moment.js'.

You should probably check to see if it fits your needs.