# How to retrieve User's CurrentCulter inside a external JS file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-plugins

I need to get the User's CurrentCulture Currency GroupSeparator and DecimalSeparator value in a external JS file like below, but below lines of code is not getting the expected result. It is not fetching values instead remains the string as it is.

```
var thousands = '<%= System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator %>';
var decimal = '<%= System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator %>';
```

In my application i need to apply currency formater for different users Culture.

Please help me.

Comment: not enough context to understand what exactly is the problem. Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: do you need the culture as the same as the server or localized for each client?

Comment: @mathiasfk I need localized culture for each client

Comment: @MarsRoverII check my updated answer

Comment: @mathiasfk I'm already using jquery-maskMoney.js. I need to pass the currency decimal and group separator there only and that value should be user's culture specific

Answer (score 0):

You can not render razor variables on external javascript file.

But you could generate a view only javascript code without tags and change the headers from request.

For example

```
 <script src="http://yourdomain/mycontroller/methodthagenerateJavascript"></script>
```

Then in your controller method apply contentType application/javascript

```
    Response.ContentType = "application/javascript";
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables like `'<%= System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator %>'` get data from the server, so its no use for you.

On the client side, you have the `navigator` object with some information, like `navigator.language`. You can then use `toLocaleString` to format it.

```
var number = 1234.56;
var lang = navigator.language; //pt-BR
number.toLocaleString(lang); //1.234,56
```

You may find other answers on this thread: [Javascript Number and Currency localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624173/javascript-number-and-currency-localization)

**Edit:** To know only the separators you could do something like:

```
separators = 1000.1.toLocaleString().replace(/\d/g, '')
thousands = separators[0];
decimal = separators[1];
```

Also related: [With a browser, how do I know which decimal separator does the client use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074660/with-a-browser-how-do-i-know-which-decimal-separator-does-the-client-use)

Comment: I'm already using jquery-maskMoney.js. I need to pass the currency decimal and group separator there only and that value should be user's culture specific.